# Handling a SSLError: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on Windows

Tags: json, python-requests, ssl-certificate, urllib

I'm using Python27, attempting to use the RealTimeTrains API. I am using the `requests.get()` function with my API log in details and the url, but I also need to use the `verify = ' '` argument in order to fix this error. Here is the line of code giving me the issue:

```
data = requests.get(api_url,auth = (api_username,api_password),verify = 'C:\Python27')
```

'C:\Python27' is where I saved the RealTimeTrains certfile (rttio.certfile with a .crt extension) - I found this in the Microsoft Edge Certificate Information window, and exported it.

I've read numerous posts which also suggest using the `cert = ''` argument of the `requests.get()` function, which requires `.pem` file. The SSLError message doesn't indicate what I need to use.

I'm new to using APIs, `.crt` files and stack overflow, so I apologies if my post quality isn't quite up to scratch yet - learning on the job here.

Thanks very much in advance for any help offered!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\RealTimeTrains_api_test.py", line 23, in <module>
    req = requests.get(api_url,auth = (api_username,api_password),verify = 'C:\\Python27')
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 70, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.6\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 497, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)
```